# How to block a thread efficiently until a particular condition is met

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am working on a multi-threaded server application in Linux using pthread library.For each client being connected there are two threads as I make two connection from device and one thread has dependency on other.until a particular condition is met First thread loop continuously in a while loop.when the condition is met the second thread sets the flag and the first thread based on that breaks the while loop and perform the required tasks.

Is running a While loop continuously in a Thread until a particular condition is met a good approach.If not please specify a better approach.

Comment: Use `mutex` and `condition`.

Comment: *Is running a While loop continuously in a Thread until a particular condition is met a good approach.*  No.  Create a semaphore. Have the second thread call `sem_wait()` in that semaphore.  Then when the first thread meets the condition, have it call `sem_post()`.

Or just use one thread.

Comment: Can you please specify what the 'particular' condition is?  Do you want to wait for a file / socket to read from or write to? Or is it a 'flag' that is set within another thread? Are you waiting on exactly one (simple) condition or is your condition more complex (like reading from one file, writing to a socket and in addition a flag from another thread)? Also it would help if you post (parts) of your source.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath it is a flag that is set within another thread based on data read from socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using pthreads, read:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait 
(or any other of pthreads' synchronizing mechanisms really).

In general, a while loop wastes CPU cycles needlessly.

Comment: For completeness the official POSIX specification to `pthread_cond_wait()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html

Comment: There is still a whole ocean of scenarios where spin lock (while loop) is more than approriate.

Comment: @SergeyA - Sure, but I can't even think of one involving "multi-threaded server application in Linux using pthread library"